# EXPTIME $\neq$ EXPSPACE consequences?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

We know that $EXPTIME ⊆ NEXPTIME ⊆ EXPSPACE$, where $EXPSPACE = DSPACE(2^{poly(n)})$.

**Question**: Is known any consequences of $EXPTIME \neq EXPSPACE$?

(nothing in [complexity zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#expspace) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE))